# How to pass variable to top-level template?

Tags: html, templates, meteor

I mean, how to pass variable to top-levet html, not into template. thx

```
<head>
  <title>{{app_name}}</title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be an obvious way of passing variables into the head section. You can't use templates inside them like you can inside the body.

However, you can set the title from JavaScript if that's what you want. You can do this in the client-side code like this:

```
document.title = "My Page Title";
```

The downside is that the title won't be set until the JavaScript loads.